# Handling fast click in xna game studio

Tags: c#, xna, click

I'm handling click events and I don't mind the lightning speed processing of the update and draw that's why I'm just using a simple button pressed event for handling clicks. But as any other programmers, I've encountered a problem while using this kind of approach, I'm adding scores like score += 100, as you would have guessed, the adding of score is very fast, in just a click I think the score added 200-400. Here's how I do it.

```
mouseStateCurrent = Mouse.GetState();
                mousePosition = new Point(mouseStateCurrent.X, mouseStateCurrent.Y);
                if (drawPauseMenu == false)
                {
                    if (pauseBtnRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            drawPauseMenu = true;
                            paused = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (binRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            playerScore += 100;
                            binSelected = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (birdBathRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            playerScore += 100;
                            birdBathSelected = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (bowlRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            playerScore += 100;
                            bowlSelected = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (cansRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            playerScore += 100;
                            cansSelected = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (paintsRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            playerScore += 100;
                            paintsSelected = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (poolRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            playerScore += 100;
                            poolSelected = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (pothRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            playerScore += 100;
                            potSelected = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    else if (tiresRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            playerScore += 100;
                            tiresSelected = 1;

                        }

                    }
                    else if (vasesRec.Contains(mousePosition))
                    {
                        if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                        {
                            playerScore += 100;
                            vasesSelected = 1;
                        }

                    }
                    mouseStatePrevious = mouseStateCurrent;
                }
```

Been trying to play with this code and tried doing it this way,

```
if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{

    if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
    {
        playerScore += 100;
        vasesSelected = 1;
    }
}
```

Still no luck with this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You've got a `mouseStatePrevious` and you're setting it correctly, but you're never using it.

Instead of:

```
if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{ // Why are you checking if the mouse is pressed AND released?
    if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
    {
        playerScore += 100;
        vasesSelected = 1;
    }
}
```

Do this:

```
if (mouseStateCurrent.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    if (mouseStatePrevious.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released)
    {
        playerScore += 100;
        vasesSelected = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I noticed it a long time ago, that I'm not using my mouseStatePrevious for anything. Well, thank you for your answer. One quick question. I can notice that some images are not really accurately placed. I'm using Rectangle for their position and size in the screen, but sometimes, it won't respond to a click. Does it mean that the mousePosition is not really hitting the rectangle of the image? But why was it drawn that visually speaking, the mouse arrow is intersecting with the image, but the code doesn't respond to it. Sorry for the long question. Thanks!

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02.aspx): `The containing rectangle must be normalized for this method to return accurate results.`

Comment: What do you mean normalized?

Comment: I'm not quite sure myself what it means. I've never worked with rectangles before, so I can't help you much here. Are you sure the `Rectangle.Contains()` method takes the rectangle's position into account? That is, if your rectangle's position and size is `{10, 10}`, will it contain `{15, 15}` (position is taken into account), or will it contain `{5, 5}` (only the size, but not the position is taken into account)?

Comment: Hmm. I think I know why. The height and width part of the rectangle doesn't really matched the images size. I just adjusted the image based on what I see. Now I'm paying the price of being inconsistent. Will try to resize the image based on my rectangles and see what happens. Thanks!